# Return states Keras- multivariate output

Tags: keras, deep-learning, lstm

With reference to this blog in the `return state` section: 
https://machinelearningmastery.com/return-sequences-and-return-states-for-lstms-in-keras/

I am trying to implement a multivariate (predicting 2 outputs- `y1` & `y2`) `stateful` `LSTM` model. Here is the snippet:

```
## defining the model
def my_model():
    input_x = Input(batch_shape=(batch_size, look_back, x_train.shape[2]), name='input')
    drop = Dropout(0.5)

    lstm_1, state_h, state_c = LSTM(50, return_sequences=False,batch_input_shape=(batch_size, look_back, x_train.shape[2]),return_state=True)(input_x)
    lstm_1_drop = drop(lstm_1)

    y1 = Dense(1, activation='linear', name='op1')(lstm_1_drop)
    y2 = Dense(1, activation='linear', name='op2')(lstm_1_drop)

    model = Model(inputs=input_x, outputs=[y1,y2])

    optimizer = Adam(lr=0.0005, decay=0.00001)
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=optimizer,metrics=['mse'])
    model.summary()
    return model

model = my_model()

history = model.fit(x_train, [y_11_train,y_22_train], epochs=1, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=0, shuffle=False)
```

**Question**

I have some issues here: I am not sure if it has been properly implemented here yet as I didn't feed the `lstm_1, state_h, state_c` in the `outputs` of `Model()` as explained in the blog, because here I have two different predictions instead of 1 as stated in the blog.

If I have to feed `lstm_1, state_h, state_c` in the `outputs` of `Model()` how can it be implemented and how it will affect the `model.fit` section.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the Blog post it seems like the author did implement state_h in the output to investigate the insides of the lstm layers. Such  an output can be usefull for an already trained network but not for training.

For training you can safely leave the information out of your output. 
If yu want to have the information during prediction, simply define a second model:

```
model = Model(inputs=input_x, outputs=[y1,y2,state_h,state_c])
```

Keras will then reuse your already trained layers and you have the information in your output without worrying about your training.

Comment: Hi @dennis-ec Thanks for your comment. If I get it correctly I will have now two models, `model1 = Model(inputs=input_x, outputs=[y1,y2])` and `model2 = Model(inputs=input_x, outputs=[y1,y2,state_h,state_c])`. 

`model1` used in `model.fit` and `model2` used in `model2.predict(x_test, batch_size=batch_size)`. And it will give me required stateful output? - Thanks once again for your input.

Comment: Your model.fit should be fine. If I understand the blog post correctly state_h and state_c which are internal representations of lstm are not meant to be training targets in the model. It looks more like the author wanted to mention them for further use cases. In an end to end training like you want to do, you don't need them in your output. The code I posted was only in the case you want to look into those states after training. Your training should be completely fine as it is.